# Undefined string[] after subscribing to observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

The below code gives a runtime error because `top5Ids` is undefined. I don't really understand why this variable is undefined when I am subscribing to the observable properly and setting the `top5Ids` variable from inside the subscriber `next` method.

The cryptoService class is just returning the result of a http.get() function, which is an observable.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cryptoDetails: CryptoDetail[];
  top5Ids: string[];

  constructor(private cryptoService: CryptoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cryptoDetails = new Array();

    this.getTop5Crypto();
    this.getCryptoData(this.top5Ids);

    const source = interval(5000).subscribe(val => this.getCryptoData(this.top5Ids))

  }

  getCryptoData(ids: string[]){
    this.cryptoDetails = [];
    console.log("get crypto")
    for(let id of ids){
      this.cryptoService.getCryptoInfo(id).subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.data;
        let cryptoDetail = new CryptoDetail(data.id, data.rateUsd, data.symbol);
        this.cryptoDetails.push(cryptoDetail);

      })
    }

    this.cryptoDetails.sort();
  }

  getTop5Crypto() : void {

    let top5CryptoIds : string[] = [];
    this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.data;
      for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        top5CryptoIds.push(data[i].baseId)
      }
      this.top5Ids = top5CryptoIds;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: You subscribe to an observable because it emits **asynchronously**. I.e. long after the method getTop5Crypto() has returned. It's like when yo send an email: you can't expect to extract data from the response immediately after you've send an email.You can only do that once the email client has notified you that the response has come back.

Comment: @JBNizet That's great. But how do I fix this code?

Comment: By reading the answer you got from patjim, for example. But most importantly, by moving away from this code for a bit, and reading and practicing about asynchrony, RxJS.

Answer (score 1):

**In Angular it is best to fully embrace functional reactive programming.**

You can rewrite your code as the following:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cryptoDetails: CryptoDetail[];
  top5Ids$: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private cryptoService: CryptoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.top5Ids$ = this.getTop5Crypto();

    timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.top5Ids$),
      switchMap((top5Ids) => this.getCryptoData(top5Ids))
    ).subscribe((cryptoDetails) => {
      this.cryptoDetails = cryptoDetails;
    })

  }


  getCryptoData(ids: string[]): Observable<CryptoDetail[]> {
    return forkJoin(ids.map(id => this.cryptoService.getCryptoInfo(id)))
            .pipe(
              map(responses => responses.map(r => new CryptoDetail(r.data.id, r.data.rateUsd, r.data.symbol)).sort())
            );
  }

  getTop5Crypto() : Observable<string[]> {
    return this.cryptoService.getCryptoMarkets().pipe(
      take(1),
      map((res: any) => res.data.filter((d, i) => i < 5).map(d => d.baseId)),
    );
  }
}
```

The idea of functional reactive programming is that we write code that reacts to things such as DOM events and Http Responses and then applies transformations to the data associated with those events via a series of (ideally pure) functions.

We try to avoid creating manual subscriptions except at the end of the pipeline (sometimes not even then if we are using Angular async pipe). This way we get a nice predictable pipeline of asynchronous events, and avoid problems such as race conditions.

The caveat is that to do these things, you must have a strong understanding of RxJS.

Comment: Nice answer! This is the way to be reactive. Appreciate it!. A little improvement - no need to do `of(ids)` in `getCryptoData`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm just working through it now. However I'm getting `Property 'data' does not exist on type {}` for the following line in getTop5Crypto; `map(res => res.data.filter((d, i) => i < 5).map(d => d.baseId)),`, this is preventing me from compiling

Comment: That is TypeScript not being able to infer the type of `res`, you need to explicitely type it as `any` - see my edit.